# Could not able start rails server when upgrading from 3.0.7 to 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and tried to upgrade the rails version from 3.0.7 to 3.2.11 for the existing application. I have installed all the relative gems and bundle install is also complete but when I start the rails server using rails s, Its showing me the errors.

```
rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on .....
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- journey (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:1
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:489:in `routes'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:551
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/anshul/herematch/config/environment.rb:5
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/anshul/herematch/config.ru:3
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /home/anshul/herematch/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/anshul/herematch/config.ru:1
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: Do you in fact see the /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/ dir in your filesystem? if so is you Path variables setup correctly. What OS?